# Org-Mode: Using Source Code Blocks in Table Formulas

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table

I would like to use source code blocks in org-mode table formulas using something similar to:

```
#+NAME: square
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var x=0
return x**2
#+END_SRC

| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 9 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$square($1)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: [Related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32935/org-mode-table-formula-and-code-blocks-function-parameter-is-cut-off-on-whitesp). `org-sbe` does Source Code Evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source: http://ehneilsen.net/notebook/orgExamples/org-examples.html#sec-8-2

```
#+NAME: sampformula
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var angle=90 :var r=2 :exports none
from math import radians, cos
result = r*cos(radians(angle))
return result
#+END_SRC

| angle |  r |             x |
|-------+----+---------------|
|    30 | 10 | 8.66025403784 |
|    45 | 10 | 7.07106781187 |
|    60 | 10 |           5.0 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe "sampformula" (angle $1) (r $2))
```