# Inline babel source blocks in org table

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

(How) can I include (or their resulting variables) in an org table?

```
* Inline code in table 
src_R{1+1}
| src_R{1+1} |
```

when exported to, e.g. HTML, results in

```
Inline code in table
2
src_R{1+1}
```

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/org-mode-using-source-code-blocks-in-table-formulas on how to include source block evaluation in table formulas. Then use table formulas for the cells where you want to see the results.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is `org-sbe` (for "source block evaluate")

```
#+NAME: function-name
#+BEGIN_SRC R
1+1
#+END_SRC

| 2 |
#+TBLFM: @1$1='(org-sbe function-name)
```